# Error in REPL: Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'X)

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to implement of Common Lisp function that computes the sum of squares.  I have this:

```
[1]> (defun sum-of-squares (x)
           (reduce +
                   (mapcar
                       #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
                       (x)
            )))
```

The REPL accepts it without complaint, but when I try to use it:

```
[2]> (sum-of-squares '(1 2 3))
```

I get this:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function X
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'X).
RETRY          :R2      Retry
STORE-VALUE    :R3      Input a new value for (FDEFINITION 'X).
ABORT          :R4      Abort main loop
```

I take it the `x` in mapcar is being interpreted as a function.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(x)` means calling a function `x`. If you want to reference `x` as a variable just put it as it is. Also, you need to pass `#'+` instead of `+` to reduce (`+` is the name of a variable you don't have, `#'+` is the name of a function +)

Comment: I propose to read a good introductory book. Free download: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun sum-of-squares (x)
  (reduce +                         ; <- 2nd mistake
          (mapcar
           #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
           (x))))                   ; <- 1st mistake
```

1st mistake: `(x)` is a function invocation.  There seems to be no function
named `x`, so the error you report is produced.  Use `x` instead.

2nd mistake: `+` is presumably not bound to a function as a value.  You need to
"fetch" it from the function space by using `function` (or `#'`, which is a
reader macro that expands to a `function` form).

3rd mistake: `x` is not a good name for a list, and it is confusing to use it
in the inner function for something different.

```
(defun sum-of-squares (list)
  (reduce #'+
          (mapcar #'(lambda (element)
                      (* element element))
                  list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You named your function SUM-OF-SQUARES but you're calling it as SS.

Comment: It was just an error in transcription.  I was using ss in the repl as I was working with it, but I changed the name for the question to make it clearer.