# Lisp grammar/formatting

Tags: lisp

Trying my hand at Lisp. I wonder though, why does:

```
(defun hello(x)
    (print x)
)
```

work fine, but:

```
(defun hello (x)
    (print(x)) ; Fails with EVAL: undefined function X.
)
```

not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in REPL: Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493467/error-in-repl-input-a-value-to-be-used-instead-of-fdefinition-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LISPs, non-empty, unquoted lists are considered (function, macro, or special form) calls.

So,

```
(print x)
```

is a function call to `print` with an argument `x`.

But,

```
(print (x))
```

is a function call to `print` with an argument equal to the value of `(x)`. But since `(x)` is also non-empty list, in order to get the value of `(x)` there is an attempt to make a call to a non-existent function `x` with no arguments.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's key to note that parentheses are not simply grouping syntax as they are in many other languages; they invoke function as well, similar to how `X.val` is not the same as `X.val()` in e.g. Python.

So in this case, you are trying to call `x` as though it were a function. But, depending on what you've passed to `hello`, `x` is not a function, and as such cannot be called.